# determining day of week based on numbers

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project with TimeDomains. In this project a TimeDomain has to be transformed to written text.
For example, the following TimeDomain is passed as a string: `[[(t2){d5}]*[(h16){h2}]]`

- t is the day of the week with t1 being Sunday
- d is the amount of days after that day, including that day, so (t2){d5} would read "Monday to Friday" (Friday is the 5th day after Monday, including Monday)

The problem here is that I can't think of a way to determine which day the d-value represents based on the t-value. If d would be a fixed value it would be easy, however d could be anything from 1 to 7.

I have the following code:

```
string dayFromName;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string s in TimeDomain)
{              
    var indexOfFirstBraceDayFrom = s.IndexOf('t') + 1;
    var indexOfLastBraceDayFrom = s.IndexOf(')');
    var dayFromTemp = s.Substring(indexOfFirstBraceDayFrom, indexOfLastBraceDayFrom - indexOfFirstBraceDayFrom).Split(' ');
    var dayFrom = dayFromTemp[0];

    var indexOfFirstBraceDayTo = s.IndexOf('d') + 1;
    var indexOfLastBraceDayTo = s.IndexOf('}');
    var dayToTemp = s.Substring(indexOfFirstBraceDayTo, indexOfLastBraceDayTo - indexOfFirstBraceDayTo).Split(' ');
    var dayTo = dayToTemp[0];

    if (dayFrom == "1")
        dayFromName = "Sunday";
    if (dayFrom == "2")
        dayFromName = "Monday";
    if (dayFrom == "3")
        dayFromName = "Tuesday";
    if (dayFrom == "4")
        dayFromName = "Wednesday";
    if (dayFrom == "5")
        dayFromName = "Thursday";
    if (dayFrom == "6")
        dayFromName = "Friday";
    if (dayFrom == "7")
        dayFromName = "Saturday";

    stringBuilder.Append(dayFromName + "to");
}
```

However I'm not sure how to define the day after "to" based on the value of D in reference to T. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can use something like `(t + d - 1) % 7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem.

Once you've worked out the day from the d value you can work out what the "to" day is from that. If you add the "d" value (taking into account the inclusivity and then do [modulo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) arithmetic on the result you can get the day number:

```
int toDay = (tValue + dValue - 1) % 7;
```

Then do the same if/switch statement (refactor your code!) as for the from day.

You'll need to parse your "t" and "d" values into integers, but having got it as an integer you'll be able to convert to the day name via the [`DayOfWeek` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) - though you'll have to offset your number to the value expected by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building an if-1-if-2-if-3 "if-tree", create a lookup dictionary:

```
var daylookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();
daylookup[1] = "Sunday";
daylookup[2] = "Monday";
...
daylookup[7] = "Saturday";
```

now, instead of writing lots of IFs, you can simply ask the dictionary:

```
dayName = daylookup[ dayNumber ];
```

This has an extra bonus. Since the day number is just an integer number, you can add, subtract, etc and nothing changes:

```
dayName = daylookup[ dayNumber + 1 ]; // the NEXT day
//or 
dayName = daylookup[ dayNumber + 2 ]; // the DAY AFTER NEXT
//or 
dayName = daylookup[ dayNumber + N ]; // the Nth day forward
```

that's the basic idea.

However, dictionaries and math is not as simple. Unless you put more, your Dictionary has only entries for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and trying to read an entry i.e. 10 (day 6+2) will throw an exception: there is no entry for "10".

That's easily solvable:

- either by adding further entries to dictionary
- or by checking if Day+Offset exceeds 7 and subtracting 7/14/21/..
- or by using modulo `%` ( not Day+Offset, but (Day+Offset)%7 )

Comment: Why not just `(System.DayOfWeek)(number - 1)`? So much code for something built into the Framework?

Comment: First time i've read about Dictionary, thanks! Saves me a bunch of if-loops!

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: because I sensed he does not know that class and thought he will benefit from learning about it much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames` with the only difference that the index starts at `0`. The below query will return Sunday assuming your current culture is English:

```
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[0])
```

So you can just do this:

```
int dayNumber = int.Parse(dayFrom) - 1;
dayFromName  = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[dayNumber];
```

Or even shorter and culture independent as pointed out by @cFrozenDeath:

```
var dayFromName2 = (System.DayOfWeek)dayNumber;
```

Comment: Why not just `(System.DayOfWeek)0` ?

Comment: Updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Ended up using your first suggestion with the CurrentCulture reference to ensure days were returned in local culture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reusing your code it will look like:

```
string dayFromName;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string s in TimeDomain)
      { 
        var dayTomName = string.Empty;
        var dayFromName = string.Empty;

        var indexOfFirstBraceDayFrom = s.IndexOf('t') + 1;
        var indexOfLastBraceDayFrom = s.IndexOf(')');
        var dayFromTemp = s.Substring(indexOfFirstBraceDayFrom, indexOfLastBraceDayFrom - indexOfFirstBraceDayFrom).Split(' ');
        var dayFrom = dayFromTemp[0];

        var indexOfFirstBraceDayTo = s.IndexOf('d') + 1;
        var indexOfLastBraceDayTo = s.IndexOf('}');
        var dayToTemp = s.Substring(indexOfFirstBraceDayTo, indexOfLastBraceDayTo - indexOfFirstBraceDayTo).Split(' ');
        var dayTo = dayToTemp[0];

        dayToName = ((System.DayOfWeek)((int.Parse(dayFrom) + int.Parse(dayTo) - 2) % 7)).ToString();
        dayFromName = ((System.DayOfWeek)(int.Parse(dayFrom) - 1)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Could you expand the above with a System.DayOfWeek notation in System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL")?

Comment: System.DayOfWeek is just enum and values are independent of current culture. If you want to make Monday first day of week instead of Sunday then you need to offset indexes by +1 and wrapping it (..) % 7 to make sure you dont get overflow.